# How to get ByWeekly Pay Period in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, if-statement

I have this code for getting First Day of week according to Today's date.

```
CultureInfo defaultCultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
DayOfWeek firstDay = _culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
DateTime firstDayInWeek = dayInWeek.Date;
while (firstDayInWeek.DayOfWeek != firstDay)
    firstDayInWeek = firstDayInWeek.AddDays(-1);
return firstDayInWeek;
```

How to return `biweeklyFirstDay` here?

Ex: Today's date is 27 May 2014. The result I get here is

```
firstDayInWeek = 26 May 2014.
```

But what I need is 19 May 2014.

Simply put, I want to return 19 May, 2 June, 16 June,  30 June, 14 July, 28 July, 11 August according to System's Today's Date.

Any example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> Payday(DateTime startDate, int howMany)
{
    int count = 0, mondays = 0;

    while (count < howMany)
    {
        startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);

        if (startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday && mondays == 0)
        {
            mondays++;
        }
        else if (startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
        {
            mondays = 0;
            count++;
            yield return startDate;
        }
    }
}
```

When called like so:

```
var payDates = Payday(DateTime.Now, 6);
```

**payDates** is equal to the next 6 pay dates, assuming you started working today.

When I use this in a console application, I get the following output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to get the week number that includes `firstDayInWeek`.

```
var calendar = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Calendar;

var week = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(firstDayInWeek, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, firstDay);
```

Then divide it by 2 and see if the remainder is 0 (indicating whether it's an even or odd number week - i.e week 18 vs 19).

The date you specified falls in week 21, so the following code detects that that's not divisible by 2, and subtracts 7 days, giving you the first day in week 20.

```
if (currentWeek % 2 != 0)
    firstDayInWeek = firstDayInWeek.AddDays(-7);
```

Comment: cool solution, but isn't modulo kind of expensive, for something that can be done with a simple increment?

Comment: Very slick, but isn't the OP asking about the pay dates in regards to an initial date? As in if you start today, we will pay you every other Monday from today?

Comment: No worries, that's how I interpreted it, maybe you're completely correct haha :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday;
        DateTime sunday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
        DateTime firstDay = sunday.AddDays((int)firstDayOfWeek);
        DateTime value = firstDay;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value.ToShortDateString());
            value = value.AddDays(14);
        }

    }
```

Comment: We're paying somebody for two days of work they haven't done? Not going to go down well with management :p

Comment: Then management should come up with better pay period specs. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int delta = _culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek - DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
while... // some criterion for continuing your quest for biweekly start days is true
{
    DateTime monday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(delta);
    delta += 14;
    // do something with each biweekly "monday" here
}
```